# MATLAB executing command line scripts for starting C++ programs? (without MEX)

Tags: linux, matlab, command-line

I am running **MATLAB 2011a** under **Ubuntu**, and I have some **C++** functions I execute from the command line such as `./community sample_networks/karate.bin -l -1 -q 0.01 > sample_networks/karateout.txt' These C++ functions produce a text file which I would like to pick up from MATLAB

I have not written these C++ functions and would like to simply have MATLAB pass a string to the command line to be executed so that the text file result can be picked up from MATLAB. I would like to avoid using **MEX** for the time being.

EDIT (using the `system` command does not work):

> > pwd
> >     ans =    /home/alex/Documents/MATLAB/MATLABsvnWorkingDir/Bloom/graphAnalysis/analysisAttempt2/functionsDownloaded/BlondelLouvainCPP/Community_BGLL_CPPLinux
> >     system('./community sample_networks/karate.bin -l -1 -q 0.01 >      sample_networks/karateout.txt > sample_networks/karateout.txt')
> >         ./community: /home/alex/matlab2011a/sys/os/glnx86/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11'     not found (required by ./community)
> >         ans = 1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to use the [system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) function.  This function will launch another executable, and wait until its finished.

Comment: I adding an edit where I show the output from the attempt with `system`, it doesn't work unless I have an error somewhere

Comment: yes, the command line I give in the EDIT was copied from the terminal where it works fine, it should work right? or is `system()` looking for OS commands?